# Parsing JSON response giving null pointer exception

Tags: apex, json, httpresponse

I'm trying to retrieve a couple fields from a json and put them into an existing account. Im starting out with just one account right now but would like to eventually pull a list of accounts and update 15-20 accounts at a time each with their own stock price and various other information like market cap. I have the following code below and am getting a nullPointerException for `result` but all of the variables have values. I've never worked with JSON before so can someone help me catch up and point out what I'm doing wrong

JSON

```
{"code":"AAPL.US","timestamp":1569593940,"gmtoffset":0,"open":220.54,"high":220.96,
"low":219.79,"close":220.24,"volume":3397713,"previousClose":219.89,
"change":0.35,"change_p":0.159}
```

APEX

```
public class StockPrices 
{    

    @future(callout=true)
    public static void getQuotes()
    {   
       //try to update stock price field on one account
       Account acct = [select id, TickerSymbol, stock_price__c from account where id ='0010V00002BeYktQAF'];

       //try to get list of accounts where tickersymbol is not null so that stock prices can be retrieved for them
       List<Account> accs = [select name, TickerSymbol, stock_price__c, stock_price_high__c from account where TickerSymbol != null];
       system.debug(accs);

       //url for api
       String url = 'https://eodhistoricaldata.com/api/real-time/AAPL.US?api_token=00000000000&period=d&fmt=json';                              

       //setup http call
       Http h = new Http();
       HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
       req.setEndpoint(url);
       req.setMethod('GET');

       HttpResponse res = h.send(req);


      if(res != null)
       {      
         StockPricesResults result = (StockPricesResults) JSON.deserialize(res.getBody(),StockPricesResults.class);
         system.debug(result);


         for (StockPricesDetails detail: result.stock_prices) 
         {
            acct.Stock_Price_High__c = detail.high;
            acct.Stock_Price__c = detail.previousClose;
         } 




          /*Saw people using this method also

          Map<String, Object> results = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(res.getBody());
          List<Object> stockPrices = (List<Object>) results.get('previousClose');
          System.debug(stockPrices);


          for (Object price: stockPrices) 
          {
            System.debug(price);
          }
          */

          update acct;

       }

    }



}
```

```
public class StockPricesResults 
{
    public StockPricesDetails[] stock_prices;
}
```

```
public class StockPricesDetails 
{
    public String code
    public Integer gmtoffset;
    public Integer open;
    public Double high;
    public Double low;
    public Double close;
    public Integer volume;
    public Double previousClose;
    public Double change;
    public Double change_p;
}
```

Comment: What line is the one erroring out?

Comment: ```StockPricesResults results``` is returning a nullPointerException. Fist line in ```if()``` statement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try it with JSON like:

```
{"stock_prices":[{"code":"AAPL.US","timestamp":1569593940,"gmtoffset":0,"open":220.54,"high":220.96, "low":219.79,"close":220.24,"volume":3397713,"previousClose":219.89, "change":0.35,"change_p":0.159}]}
```

Your code expects an object with a property "stock_prices" that is an array of objects.

If that isn't what you want, and you need to handle the given JSON then change the code to parse a single instance of StockPricesDetails:

```
StockPricesDetails details = (StockPricesDetails) JSON.deserialize(res.getBody(), StockPricesDetails.class);
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to change the format of the json, im pulling it from an api. How would i change the code to deal with it?

Comment: So what if its an array like this?```[{"code":"AAPL.US","timestamp":1569610380,"gmtoffset":0,"open":220.54,"high":220.96,"low":217.2814,"close":217.47,"volume":18222872,"previousClose":219.89,"change":-2.42,"change_p":-1.101},{"code":"GOOG.US","timestamp":1569610380,"gmtoffset":0,"open":1243.01,"high":1244,"low":1214.45,"close":1214.53,"volume":888960,"previousClose":1241.39,"change":-26.86,"change_p":-2.164}]```

Comment: You parse it as an array of StockPricesDetails directly: StockPricesDetails[] details = (StockPricesDetails[]) JSON.deserialize(res.getBody(), StockPricesDetails[].class); (or as List<StockPricesDetails> which is identical).

Comment: System.JSON Exception: For input string: "NA" at [line:1, column: 397] -------{["code":"BCP.US","timestamp":"NA","gmtoffset":"NA","open":"NA","high":"NA","low":"NA","close":"NA","volume":"NA","previousClose":"NA","change":"NA","change_p":"NA"]} How would i handle this?

Comment: @Tyler I suggest you raise a separate question. I think you have an issue where the text "NA" is being provided to mean "Not Applicable" and this is being applied to fields that have a type (like a number or a timestamp) where such a value is invalid. My suggestion would be to perform a regex search and replace for ':\s*"NA"' with ': ""' to remove all "NA" text and leaving empty property values before parsing the JSON. Anyway, if you want a better answer you should provide a new question with more context about what NA is and what the various property types are etc.!

Comment: I wasn't sure how to do that so i took the easy way out and changed all the data types to string and then convert them into decimals if they arent equal to 'NA'

Comment: That's not very nice code though... if you had asked a separate question I could have suggested the actual code...

Comment: It seems that im not allowed to ask anymore questions. Can we chat

Comment: We can start a separate chat, sure.

Comment: I dont think im able to create a chat, could you invite me. Btw i tried ```String body = res.getBody();
         body.replaceAll('\"[^\"]*\":NA','');``` but it doesn't work for me

Comment: I am unable to start a chat against your user by the look of it. As I mentioned before, why don't you ask a replacement question?

Comment: Because i'm not allowed to ask anymore questions. This site is pretty frustrating.

Comment: It has some strangeness, but it is still a valuable source of help! Sorry you've hit a roadblock though...

Comment: i just simply used ```String body = res.getBody();
         body = body.replaceAll('NA','0');```

Comment: Fine as long as "NA" can't appear anywhere else.